# Bizarre PDF: file displayed ok yesterday, today shows only dots and lines

Tags: pdf, virus, file-corruption

Yesterday my wife sent me a PDF file as an email attachment. I opened it on MacOS and printed it. Today she says the file (on her Windows 10 computer) is "corrupted". So I tried re-opening the email attachment -- and my copy is also corrupted: it displays as boxes, lines and dots. Same thing on my iPhone.

It's as if the PDF had a built-in Mission Impossible timed self-destruct.

I tried converting it to ps (using pdftops). I've looked at it using pdfinfo. Nothing stands out.

Any ideas what might be going on, or what I can try?

Apologies if this is not the appropriate place for the question -- a web search didn't throw up anything similar.

Comment: PDFs can include javascript which could potentially "hide" the original content so it's possible... It shouldn't be able to actually modify the contents of the file  that was emailed though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867341/removing-javascript-print-code-embedded-in-pdf is vaguely related.

Comment: Most PDF viewers have a setting for disabling JavaScript by default. Which one are you using?

Comment: Using MacOS 10.14 Preview. But as I said, I also converted it with the command line pdftops. The PostScript file (also viewed with Preview) looks the same.